# In Rust tests, how to assert_eq some json that keeps reordering its keys

Tags: rust, serde

My Rust lib does some operations on JSON, and in unit tests I need to ensure the correctness of the lib.   Yet, json to string conversion keeps key order unstable.  I do NOT want to modify the lib to include json sorting, but I do need to compare the results effectively in my unit tests. What can I do to simplify this comparison?

Comment: How are you reading the JSON? Are you using `serde_json`? And can you provide the code you've got so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest answer would be to parse both strings and compare the parsed values for equality.  This compares the strings *semantically* instead of literally, which is what you want anyway.  Aside from key order, other non-semantic differences in the strings (like amounts of insignificant whitespace or escaped vs unescaped characters) will also be ignored.

```
assert_eq!(
    a.parse::<serde_json::Value>().unwrap(),
    b.parse::<serde_json::Value>().unwrap()
);
```

If your library itself doesn't depend on `serde_json`, you can include it as a [dev dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/dev_dependencies.html) to have it available during tests without requiring users of your library to depend on it transitively.